# TCPDF ERROR: Error in 1D barcode string

Tags: php, barcode, tcpdf

Getting the following error while generating 1D barcode images in pdf document with array of barcodes using tcpdf  module.

> "TCPDF ERROR: Error in 1D barcode string"

```
if (file_exists("data1.txt")) 
{
echo("<B>File Exists data1.txt</B>");
$arrText = file("data1.txt");
for ($i=0; $i<count($arrText); $i++) 
{
echo("<P>$arrText[$i]</P>");
$pdf->write1DBarcode("'".chop($arrText[$i])."'", 'UPCA', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');
$pdf->Ln();
}
} 
else 
{
echo("<B>Cannot find file</B>");
exit;
}
```

Comment: What string are you trying to use as a barcode string?

Answer (score 1):

Normally this means that you are try to create a barcode using unsupported characters.
Each barcode type support only a character subset so, it is up to you to verify the code.

Keep in mind UTF-8 characters are normally not accepted. Check the documentation of the barcode type you are trying to use for further information, good-luck.

Comment: if barcode is hardcoded there is no issue.. if i am trying to pass dynamically with array values then only i am getting the errors .. $pdf->write1DBarcode('725975724194', 'UPCA', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');
$pdf->Ln();

Comment: in your array, you have special caracters?